# Overflow a grid child with a large amount of content without setting absolute height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5890yaL/4/)

```
.grid {
  height:100%;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.lots-of-content-div {
  height:100%;
  background-color:orange;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```
<div class="grid">
  <p>Let's call this one the header</p>
  <div class="lots-of-content-div">
    <ul>
      // A reaaaaally long list!
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the `lots-of-content-div` div be scrollable, rather than the entire body **without setting absolute heights**, so I can paste the component anywhere and have it fill the entire vertical space. How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

```js
parentHeight = jQuery(".grid").parent().outerHeight();
pHeight = jQuery(".grid").find("p").outerHeight(); 
jQuery(".lots-of-content-div").css({'height': parentHeight-pHeight});
```

```css
    .any-parent-element {
      height: 300px;
    }
    .grid {
      height:100%;
      display:grid;
      grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
      background-color:yellow;     
    }

    .lots-of-content-div {
      height:0px;
      background-color:orange;
      overflow-y:auto;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="any-parent-element">
    <div class="grid">
      <p>Let's call this one the header</p>
      <div class="lots-of-content-div">
        <ul>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
          <li>Hello!</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: 100vh in height is 100% of view height of user screen. Hope this can help.

Comment: Can I limit myself to percent-of-parent usage? I want to be able to put it inside some smaller div as well, that does not necessarily take the entire vh.

Comment: There is no universal solution only with CSS. I think, better use jQuery to get parent element height and add this height to this block. If you are able to use jQuery, i can write down a complete solution for you.

Comment: Just edited the answer, you can see the new solution.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work without jQuery, it's enough to add `height:100%` to `html, body`. Weird that doing the same in my project did not help (adding `height:100%` to all of the ancestors of the overflow div).